# Audit.net framework in asp.net mvc performance using AuditIdentityDbContext

Tags: audit.net

I am using the audit.net and audit.entityframework for audit logging changes made in a asp.net MVC 5 application using entityframework code first principle.

On a user webform multiple roles can be assigned to a user.

Using the following short loop in the action of the controller:

```
foreach (var role in roles)
                {
                    base.UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, role.Name);
                }
```

I get a log of approx 700 lines in sqlprofiler.

However if I enable the audit.net logger in my Startup.cs:

```
 Audit.EntityFramework.Configuration.Setup()
                .ForAnyContext(x => x.IncludeEntityObjects(true)
                .ForEntity<User>(config => config
                .Ignore(u => u.PasswordHash))
                .AuditEventType("{context}:{database}"))
                .UseOptIn().IncludeAny(t.Name.ToLower().IndexOf("user") >= 0);
```

The result is more than 10.000 sql profiler records created for the same action, assigning 51 roles to a single user. Also the 51 event records by audit.net have each a datafield with rougly 2 million characters asccording to the ms-sql len function.

Can anybody explain the reason for this massive sql activity caused by enabling logging on the userroles table and how to avoid it.

Comment: The SQL profiler _record count_ is not a good indicator. I guess you're using an IdentityDbContext, could you share your context declaration? Also note you could define a [custom action](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#custom-actions) in order to debug and see the AuditEvent content before it's saved.